# Got Error when submitting an array of striing arrays in a function in Solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

**Got this error message in Remix IDE** : transact to Countriesy.storeABatchOfCountries errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 39 of the JSON data

My Function is supposed to take an array of 10 array of 6 string and store them inside the countriesMap mapping.

**Here is the function code** :

```
  //Function to store a batch of a maximum 10 countries in the Contract at the same time...
  function storeABatchOfCountries(string[6][10] calldata countriesData)
    external
    isOwner
  {
    uint8 _countryCounter;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < countriesData.length; i++) {
      countriesMap[countriesData[i][5]] = Country(
        countriesData[i][0],
        countriesData[i][1],
        countriesData[i][2],
        countriesData[i][3],
        countriesData[i][4],
        countriesData[i][5],
        true
      );
      _countryCounter++;
    }
    numberOfCountries = _countryCounter;
  }
```

**And Here is the data I'm submitting to it**:

```
[
    ["+376", "Europe", "Andorra", "Euro", unicode"", "AD"],
    ["+971", "Asia", "United Arab Emirates", "Dirham", unicode"", "AE"],
    ["+93", "Asia", "Afghanistan", "Afghani", unicode"", "AF"],
    [
      "+1268",
      "North America",
      "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "Dollar",
      unicode"",
      "AG"
    ],
    ["+1264", "North America", "Anguilla", "Dollar", unicode"", "AI"],
    ["+355", "Europe", "Albania", "Lek", unicode"", "AL"],
    ["+374", "Asia", "Armenia", "Dram", unicode"", "AM"],
    [
      "+599",
      "North America",
      "Netherlands Antilles",
      "Guilder",
      unicode"",
      "AN"
    ],
    ["+244", "Africa", "Angola", "Kwanza", unicode"", "AO"],
    ["+672", "Antarctica", "Antarctica", "", unicode"", "AQ"]
  ]
```

Comment: Try without `unicode` keyword

Comment: @kj-crypto
Got typeError without the unicode for emoji string in solidity...

Comment: @kj-crypto ..Thanks... your answer finally work... still don't know why since solidity recommand putting unicode before any string that contain emojis...

Comment: Error message says that it can't  encode json. Column number indicates `unicode`. Unicode works in solidity but not outside it, like then when you make call of contract function from web3.js or remix

Comment: @kj-crypto .. Got it clear now. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `unicode` keyword from list items like `unicode""`. Json parser can't encode `unicode` word. It works only inside solidity code.

As an example consider following contract:

```
contract Flags {
   string public flag = unicode"";

   function setFlag(string memory _flag) public {
       flag = _flag;
   }
}
```

and following test case in `brownie`:

```py
from brownie import accounts, Flags

def test_unicode_string_setup():
    contract = Flags.deploy({'from': accounts[0]})
    assert contract.flag() == ""

    # no unicode keyword    
    contract.setFlag("", {'from': accounts[0]})
    assert contract.flag() == ""
```